# No Terminal No Dashboard and No Window border in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, unity-dash

I upgraded Ubuntu 12.02 to 14.04 and upgraded all packages with command `sudo get-apt -f install`. I dont know what happened but I am not even able to open Terminal or any applications. I can't see dashboard and window border. I dont know what to do? Please help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Ubuntu Desktop and/or Unity didn't install correctly. Try this:

1. Reboot your computer.
2. At the grub menu, select Advanced options for Ubuntu and select the Recovery kernel.
3. When the recovery menu comes up, select the option for the root prompt.
4. Type `mount -o rw,remount /` The next steps require you to have an internet connection.
5. Connect with LAN.
6. Run `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.
7. If it says it's already installed, add `--reinstall` after `install`.
8. Run `apt-get install unity`
9. See 6.
10. After the installations finish, reboot.

Comment: Did not fix the problem after upgrading from U14.04.3 to U14.04.5 using the HWE "Install" option in the Software Updater window.  Not happy Canonical!